# Уникальный идентификатор телефона

Tags: android

Я работаю над игрой и мне нужно каждому пользователю дать `id` для того, чтобы сохранить данные. Как мне получить уникальный идентификатор телефона, который никогда не меняется и не является важной информацией? Если путь неправильный, подскажите какой правильный.

Comment: вроде бы любой id можно поменять.

Answer (score 3):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),                                                        Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Но этот id поменяется, если сделать hardreset. Более того, этот id как раз и предназначен для Ваших целей - уникальный id.